# Color change of the selected text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, getselection

I want to highlight feature which will change the color of the selected text using Javascript. I am using the following method.

```
function android_selection_highlight(replacrmenthtml){
    try {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

            var selectionStart = $("<span style=\"color:red\">");
            var startRange = document.createRange();
            startRange.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);


            var selectionEnd = $("</span>");
            var endRange = document.createRange();
            endRange.setStart(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);

            startRange.insertNode(selectionStart[0]);
            endRange.insertNode(selectionEnd[0]);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {

    }
}
```

But it is giving DOM exception when I am calling the method. I think that when I am inserting starting span tag in front of the selected text, it is disrupting the DOM structure as there is no end tag at that moment. How to solve this problem?

**Edited**:
There will a highlight button. Selecting the text, if user click on the highlight button, the text color of the selected text will change.

Comment: CSS-only solution not enough? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-selection

Comment: Will u please explain it clearly. i am not getting this " I want to highlight feature".

Answer (score 6):

if on select u want to change color use this code.

```
    ::-moz-selection { color: red;}
    ::selection { color: red; }
```

Comment: It is not on select color change, I want to change the background color permanently, even after deselection.

Comment: ok, i got it. But it was not mentioned in your post that you need permanent color change. I will provide the exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a JS question, but there is a CSS selector which allows you to do this.

```
::selection {
  color: red;
}
```

If the browser considers that you've made a choice which is not accessible, it might override your colours. Not everything can be styled in this way, but colours and background colours can.

More information:

- [::selection on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/)
- [::selection on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection)

Comment: It is not on select color change, I want to change the background color permanently, even after deselection.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS Custom Highlight API, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Custom_Highlight_API, is designed to do exactly what you want. In JS you can mark ranges as having a named highlight style, and in CSS you define what that highlight is. The browser should do something that looks like selection, but is persistent.

For example:

```
<style>
  div::highlight(foo) {
    background-color: green;
  }
</style>
<div id="highlighted">This is highlighted text</div>
<script>
  let r = new Range();
  r.setStart(highlighted, 0);
  r.setEnd(highlighted, 1);
  let h = new Highlight(r);
  CSS.highlights.set('foo', h);
</script>
```